# HTML back to back image with gap

Tags: html

I wanted to add 2 image back to back with some gap in between, however my code below doesn't leave any gap, what should I add to leave a gap in between the images?

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column"><a href="....."><img style="float: left" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e21362_745c8df449d844a38a92f64d4d1af4a4~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_200,h_55,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/appstore.png" width="150" height="40"> </a></div>
<div class="column"><a href="....."> <img style="float: left" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e21362_2712e9b89fa64756bc60b9e084624341~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_200,h_55,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/playstore.png" width="150" height="40"></a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is class `row` defined? How is class `column` defined?

Comment: Use flexbox to align items next to each other, use `gap` to specify the gap of these items.

Comment: @Daweo, row and column are default.

Comment: @cloned, I changed it to flexbox, but flexbox doesn't have gap attributes right? <div class="flex-container">
<div><a href="..."><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e21362_745c8df449d844a38a92f64d4d1af4a4~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_200,h_55,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/appstore.png" width="150" height="40"> </a></div>
<div><a href="..."><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e21362_2712e9b89fa64756bc60b9e084624341~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_200,h_55,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/playstore.png" width="150" height="40"> </a></div>
</div>

Comment: Please update your question using the `[<>]` snippet editor instead of posting HTML in a comment

Comment: `.selector {display:flex; gap: 10px}` of course it has it, even tough it can be confusing to find in the documentations. but it works and is supported on modern browsers. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/gap/

Comment: I manage to add the gap using the code below

Comment: <div class="row">
<div class="column"><a href="..."><img style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e21362_745c8df449d844a38a92f64d4d1af4a4~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_200,h_55,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/appstore.png" width="150" height="40"> </a></div>
<div class="column"><a href="..."> <img style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom:10px;" src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/e21362_2712e9b89fa64756bc60b9e084624341~mv2.png/v1/fill/w_200,h_55,al_c,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01/playstore.png" width="150" height="40"></a></div>
</div>

Comment: Thanks @cloned! It is good to know, would read up on the "gap" attribute and also try it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase anyone I looking for an answer for this; I manage to add the gap using the code below.

```
<div class="row"> <div class="column"><a href="..."><img style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;" src="static.wixstatic.com/media/…" width="150" height="40"> </a></div> <div class="column"><a href="..."> <img style="float: left; padding-right: 10px; padding-bottom:10px;" src="static.wixstatic.com/media/…" width="150" height="40"></a></div> </div>
```